# Confusion over how to share and modify class level data between instances.

Tags: python

I don't understand how 'static' class data works in Python. I'm attempting to replicate a pattern I used often in Java where I create a central faux-database class, and give instances of it to any classes that need it.

However, here's where I'm lost with Python, it seems like anytime I try to access the 'static' variable, I create an instance level one. It's very confusing.

Here's the code:

```
import csv 

class Database(object):
    data = list()
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def connect(self, location=None):
        path = '.\\resources\\database\\'
        with open(path + 'info.csv', 'rU') as f:
            csv_data = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
            for row in csv_data:
                self.data.append(Entry(*row))
```

As you can see, pretty straight forward. I declare `data` outside of the `init`, which I believe makes it class level. I then loop through a csv file and append each row's cell fields to the `data` list.

Here's where I get confused. The first thing I wanted to do was slice of the first entry in the `data` list (this just had the column named from the excel sheet). But in doing this, it seems to create an instance level version of `data` rather than modifying the class level `data` that I want.

So, I modified the code as follows

```
import csv 

class Database(object):
    data = list()
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def connect(self, location=None):
        path = '.\\resources\\database\\'
        with open(path + 'info.csv', 'rU') as f:
            csv_data = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
            for row in csv_data:
                self.data.append(Entry(*row))
            self.data = self.data[1:]  ## <--- NEW LINE HERE
```

As you can see, I tried to slice it as I would any other list, but in doing so, it makes (seemingly) a local version of `data`

In my `main()`, I have the following code to test out some of the attributes:

```
def main():
    settings = Settings()

    db = csv_loader.Database()
    db.connect(settings.database)
    print 'gui.py:', db.data[0].num
    print 'gui.py:', db.data[0].name
    print 'gui.py:', len(db.data)
```

This behaves just as expected. It has 143 entries, because of the previous slice operation.

Now, I have another class which has an instance of `Database()` *but* the slice had no effect.

```
self.db = Database()
self.settings = Settings()
print 'tabOne.py:', self.db.data[0].conf_num
print 'tabOne.py:', self.db.data[0].conf_name
print len(self.db.data)
```

The printout from this class shows that there are 144 elements in the list -- so the slice operation didn't actually modify the class level `data`.

What am I missing? Am I attempting to modify the class level variable incorrectly or something?

Comment: Python is not Java... It generally is not a good idea to try and replicate Java patterns in Python, they often are not needed at all.

Comment: Using the `@classmethod` is best answer, IMHO. But it would also be more efficient to just skip the first line and not append that to the original list, rather than read everything in then make a new copy just to remove the first line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're basically right about how to go about doing this, however, list slicing creates a copy, so the line:

```
self.data = self.data[1:]
```

creates a **copy** of the data and then assigns it to a new **instance attribute**.

Here's how all of this works: when an attribute is looked up for an instance, python first looks in the instances's `__dict__` for the attribute.  If it isn't in the instance's `__dict__`, python next looks in the class's `__dict__` and then parent class's `__dict__`s (following the method resolution order).  So, when you do first start accessing `self.data` (to append to it), you don't find `data` in the instance's `__dict__`, so python is using `data` from the class's `__dict__`.  But, when you explicitly assign to `self.dict`, you're all of a sudden adding an entry into the instance's `__dict__` which will be used from that point on.

There are a couple of workarounds:

```
Database.data = self.data[1:]
```

would work just fine, or you could use slice assignment to modify the `self.data` list in place:

```
self.data[:] = self.data[1:]
```

Or any other method which modifies the list in place:

```
self.data.pop(0)
```

---

A final option, which is probably the most *explicit* of the bunch is to change `connect` to a `classmethod`:

```
@classmethod
def connect(cls, location=None):
    path = '.\\resources\\database\\'
    with open(path + 'info.csv', 'rU') as f:
        csv_data = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_data:
            cls.data.append(Entry(*row))
        cls.data = cls.data[1:]
```

Now the first argument to the method is the *class*, not the *instance* and so we've changed the customary `self` to an equally customary `cls` (although I've seen `klass` as well).  This method can be invoked from an instance or from the class itself:

```
database_instance = Database()
database_instance.connect()

Database.connect()
```

---

---

In the comments, there is mention of using a module for this sort of thing.  A `module` allows state to transported throughout your program very simply as well and they end up acting a lot like a singleton -- in fact they're often recommended for python instead of singletons:

```
"""
Module `Database` (found in Database.py)
"""
data = []

def connect(self, location=None):
    global data
    path = '.\\resources\\database\\'
    with open(path + 'info.csv', 'rU') as f:
        csv_data = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_data:
            data.append(Entry(*row))
        data = data[1:]
```

Now in another module you just:

```
import Database
Database.connect()
print Database.data
```

etc. etc.

Comment: mgilson explain well why it happened but I think you want to use a global variable which is owned by a database module

Comment: @XavierCombelle: And what makes you think so? Class variables are quite fine here, except that he was lacking some basic concepts

Comment: mgilson appears to nail the answer.  I'm just going to chime in and say that I find using "Database.data" as opposed to "self.data" is, IMO, a much clearer way to refer to what is a class attribute.

Comment: Note that by using `cls` in a `classmethod`, you changed behaviour for the subclass case; in a subclass `cls` in a `classmethod` is always `type(self)`, while `Database.data` hardcodes the path to a specific class. Subclasses will get their own copy of `data` when using `cls` in a `classmethod`.

Comment: @Abhijit because module level things are powerful concept that has no equivalent in java

Comment: @XavierCombelle -- Added a quick summary about how a module could be used for this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Yes, each unique type will share state with all other instances of that particular `type`.